# Bootstrap modal freezing page after close

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So I have a page with datatables that opens a modal and you can edit some values there.

When I click de "confirm" button I run an AJAX that works perfectly and in the "success:" I want to dismiss the modal.

Using `$('#exampleModal').modal('hide');` the backdrop stays there and the user have to reload the page.
After searching here a I saw the solution by adding:

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

At this point the modal dismiss perfectly and the "shadow" effect disappear but the page gets frozen. This mean it will scroll, but any link/button wont work, dont event change the cursor icon.

edit (more info):
Closing the modal with the "cancel" button using `data-dismiss="modal"` or clicking outside the modal works perfect.

Using the `data-dismiss="modal"` in the "AJAX button" gives the same problem described.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, if i understood your problem right use `$('#modalname').modal('hide');` and in the request.done just reload the page by `window.location = window.location;`. This solved my problem.

Comment: reloading the page doesn't solve the actual problem